# StructureMap: Multithreaded env. No default instance defined for PluginFamily

Tags: multithreading, structuremap

I'm dealing with structuremap error for quite a while.
The error is:

> StructureMap.StructureMapException: **StructureMap Exception Code: 202**
>   No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily
>   SomeNamespace.ISomeInterface, SomeNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Our project is fully multithreaded and StructureMap can be called several times per second with different profile name each time.

StructureMap setting is done when application starts.
I use the StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry:

```
var registry = new Container(...some parameters settings...);
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.IncludeRegistry(registry));
```

And Container is:

```
class Container : StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry
{
    public Container(...Some settings parameters...)
    {
        For<IConnG>().Use<DG>()
            .Ctor<string>("user").Is(some parameter)
            .Ctor<string>("pass").Is(some parameter)
            .Ctor<string>("site").Is(some parameter)
            .Ctor<string>("DateFormat").Is(some parameter);

        For<IRPG>().Use<RPG>();

        Scan(asm =>
        {
            asm.TheCallingAssembly();
            asm.Include(type => type.IsAbstract == false && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseC)));
            asm.With(new RegistrationConvention());
        });

        var actionName = (enumA)Enum.Parse(typeof(enumA), some parameter);

        switch (actionName)
        {
            case enumA.ActionA:
                Profile(enumA.ActionA.ToString(), (pe) =>
                {
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For<IXXX>().Use<DefaultXXX>();
                    **pe.For<IAction<SomeNamespace.SearchParams, SomeNamespace.SearchParams>>().Use<DefaultSearchParams>();**
                    pe.For...;
                });
                break;

            case enumA.ActionB:
                Profile(enumA.ActionB.ToString(), (pe) =>
                {
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For<IXXX>().Use<DefaultXXX>();
                    **pe.For<IAction<SomeNamespace.SearchParams, SomeNamespace.SearchParams>>().Use<DefaultSearchParams>();**
                    pe.For...;
                });
                break;

            case enumA.ActionC:
                Profile(enumA.ActionC.ToString(), (pe) =>
                {
                   pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For<IXXX>().Use<DefaultXXX>();
                    **pe.For<IAction<SomeNamespace.SearchParams, SomeNamespace.SearchParams>>().Use<XXXSearchParams>();**
                    pe.For...;
                });
                break;

            case enumA.ActionD:
                Profile(enumA.ActionD.ToString(), (pe) =>
                {
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For...;
                    pe.For<IXXX>().Use<DefaultXXX>();
                    **pe.For<IAction<SomeNamespace.SearchParams, SomeNamespace.SearchParams>>().Use<DefaultSearchParams>();**
                    pe.For...;
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The RegistrationConvention is:

```
public class RegistrationConvention : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    #region IRegistrationConvention Members

    public void Process(Type type, StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry registry)
    {
        var interfaces = new List<Type>
        {
            type.GetInterface("IInfo`1"),
            type.GetInterface("IBook`1"),
            type.GetInterface("IConf`1"),
            type.GetInterface("IClxP`1"),
            type.GetInterface("ICanc`1"),
            type.GetInterface("IConf2`1"),
            type.GetInterface("IMaxP`1"),
            type.GetInterface("IAction`1")
        };

        interfaces
            .ForEach(contractType =>
                     {
                         if (contractType != null)
                         {
                             registry.For(contractType).Use(type);
                         }
                     });
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I'm calling StructureMap in code like that:

```
var container = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Container;

container.SetDefaultsToProfile(Some profile name);

var adaptor = container.GetInstance<IAction<SomeNamespace.SearchParams, SomeNamespace.SearchParams>>();
```

This code is called by many threads, and I'm getting this error not all the times, but quite a lot.
When printing out WhatDoIHave() it indicates it has it.

I'll be glad to have any suggestion/correction.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It was hard to solve, but finally I got there!
The problem was I misused StructureMap:
StructureMap, as far as I correctly grasped the intention of using it, is intended to dynamicaly load settings once, when application loads.
In our project, we're switching profiles many times per seconds and trying to retrieve an instance based on that profile. We got many exceptions like it doesn't recognize the default instance although WhatDoIHave() showed the opposite.
The problem was exactly that - calling the Container from many threads and switching profiles upon each request.

So, for a reminder, when application starts, for each profile I added its settings to the only one Container:

```
var registry = new OurRegistry(settings parameters..., profileName);

StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.IncludeRegistry(registry));
```

And in many places in code, I used to call StructureMap like that:

```
  var container = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Container;

  container.SetDefaultsToProfile(profileName);

  var adaptor = container.GetInstance<ISomeInterface<ConcreteType>>();
```

This code was used parallel and each thread used another profile.

So, as a fix I created a Container per profile!

```
var registry = new OurRegistry(settings parameters..., profileName);

var container = new StructureMap.Container(registry);
```

And I stored each container in our code, not on StructureMap as before, so each profile-prone thread is using it's own profiled Container.
That's even faster then before because you don't have to switch profiles so much, only once!

And no more #$@!@ 202 exception :)